# Webpacker: What is `source_entry_path` and `source_path`?

Tags: webpacker

In [Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) what is the difference between `source_entry_path` and `source_path`? I'm not seeing it explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source_path:` is the parent directory where your pack folders and files live.

It is usually called `javascript` or `frontend` under `app` directory.

`app/javascript`

`app/frontend`

`source_entry_path` defines your pack directory name and all your entry files go there. By convention it is called `packs`. Keep in mind that each entry file treated separately in this directory.

These can be named anything you want, make sure these directories exist.

So when you have `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in your layout file, webpacker knows to find `application.js` file in `app/javascript/packs` based on what you have for `source_path:` and `source_entry_path` in webpacker.yml